# Yii2-debug missing page

Tags: php, debugging, yii2

I am using Yii2 (basic), everything works like a charm except for one little problem, one page doesn't show debug panel, also this page doesn't appear in Yii2 debugger history. When i asked this question on yii official irc, i was told to update yii2-debug, so i did, i updated it from 2.0.0 to currently newest 2.0.7, but it did not really help me, i dont see any difference.

To be specific:

- The page will load and show all the content with no errors, the only thing missing is the debug panel.
- The debug panel works like a charm for all other pages (even in the same controller)

**Could this behavior be caused by my code?**

Or is it just problem on their (yii dev team) side and there is no way i could fix this at the moment?

EDIT: I tracked down and solved the problem. 
This bug was caused by following foreach loop in one of functions in my model.

```
foreach($SROut as $key => $in){
    $stockDetails = $stock->getStockDetailsByID($SROut[$key]['ID_Stock']);
    $SROut[$key]['Name'] = $stockDetails['Name'];
    $SROut[$key]['Units'] = $stockDetails['Units'];
}
```

But when i changed it to:

```
foreach($SROut as $key => $in){
    $stockDetails = $stock->getStockDetailsByID($key['ID_Stock']);
    $SROut[$key]['Name'] = $stockDetails['Name'];
    $SROut[$key]['Units'] = $stockDetails['Units'];
}
```

The debug panel showed up, but it broke my code, now the foreach loop is not working as it should, but this is something i can handle on my own.

To answer my own question:

**Yes it was caused by my code.**

Comment: you use a different layout page for this page?

Comment: do other actions in same controllers work with debug panel ? and as was asked, do you use different layout ? do you use any javascript that might break html head section or something like that ?

Comment: Just in case somebody else, falls into this. Yes, I had this same issue, for certain my yii2 configuration was correct, as I was using the debug bar. But after a change in database structure(not matching yet model's structure), the bar disappeared. So it was not an issue on Yii version, the place to look into, is this last change on DB structure o differences between model and DB structure. And error handling is not manifesting this case.